# Remove reference from Add/remove program with Wix

Tags: wix

I have created a wix build, which does the following
    1. Install the files in temporary location.
    2. Then I call a custom Action to copy the files into a different location and does messaging of some of the config files.
    3. Display a message to user that installation is complete.
    4. and then Exit the MSI.

```
PROBLEM: The reference to the MSI exists in control panel add remove program.
```

How can I remove the reference of the project from add remove program? 
Is it possible within the same WIX build? 
What are the alternatives to achieve it?

Thanks,
M

Comment: You don't want the program to be removable?

Comment: no... I want the MSI to be self-removable, as I have done all I need to do in custom action (even removing the original install files and removing entries from registry etc)... so at the end of the MSI I don't want the reference of the MSI to be present in add/remove programs. Hope it makes sense !!

Comment: It seems like you don't want to use Windows Installer at all. Visibility in Add/Remove Program is controllable. Presence in the Uninstall key has nothing at all to do with being uninstallable. It's just a valued added feature of installation systems that run on Windows that Windows Installer participates in. Windows Installer is a transactional managed installation system. If you want to copy some files and tweak some settings, you'd use a different installation system: NSIS or a program you could write yourself. You shouldn't pretend that your installer conforms to Windows Installer standards

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you want to prevent your application from being displayed in the Add or Remove Programs list of Control Panel.

Then you need to set property `ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT` in to 1.

```
<Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1" />
```

Read more about [ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And also if you want it to show into add or remove programs, but remove or modify functions disabled then use ARP ENTRY properties.

```
<Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
<Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="1" />
<Property Id="ARPNOREMOVE" Value="1" />
```

Refer for More Info:  [ARP ENTRY](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/add-or-remove-programs-entries)

And if you don't want your program to be uninstall using `msiexec` also you can add condition like

```
<Condition Message="Uninstall is not supported">REINSTALL or Not Installed</Condition>.
```

Uninstall using `msiexec.exe /x` will give pop-up saying uninstall is not supported and will quit.

Comment: Hi Nimish...that's correct. I got this soln but the problem with ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1 is that it still holds the reference i.e. if you run msiexec /x myinstaller.msi, it will uninstall the MSI... ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 1 will simply prevent it from displaying in add/remove program

Comment: @user1961100 Check updated answer. it will simply aborts uninstall saying uninstall not supported. I hope this is what you are looking for.but remember preventing application from uninstall you wont be able to upgrade/patch your application.